# Show ACF field from custom taxonomy and display on the single template

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type called products, which I have attached a custom taxonomy called Product Categories.

On each of the Product Categories, I have used Advanced Custom Fields to add fields such as product category colour, logo etc.

Initially, I'm trying to display the Product Category colour as a background colour for all of the products that fall inside that specific Product Category.

I've tried using the same method as I used to display the colour on the actual Product Category page (taxonomy-product_category.php), by adding this to the top of the page:

```
// get the current taxonomy term
$term = get_queried_object();

// vars
$category_colour_primary = get_field('category_colour_primary', $term);
```

and then referencing it later on like this:

```
<div class="container-flex" style="background-color:<?php echo $category_colour_secondary; ?>;">
</div>
```

This works great on each of the Product Category  pages, but doesn't seem to work on the single page template (single-products.php).

I feel I need to get the name (or terms?!) of the current product's taxonomy and then display them as usual...

I've come to a bit of a dead end and I'm unsure what I need to try next...

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel I've tried a million things, but can't quite get my head around it. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this...

```php
// Assume there is only one category.
$product_category = get_the_terms($post, 'product-category')[0];

$cat_fields = get_fields("term_$product_category");

$color = $cat_fields['category_colour_primary'];
```

You could also do this...

```php
// Assume there is only one category.
$product_category = get_the_terms($post, 'product-category')[0];

$color = get_field('category_colour_primary', "term_$product_category");
```

Comment: Thanks for this Daniel - Adding either of those to the top of my page just crashes the page unfortunately - Can I ask what the [0] is there for? Each of the products will only have one category :)

Comment: `get_the_terms()` returns and array. So `[0]` grabs the first item off the array. If you turn on error reporting what error does the page show?

Comment: If I try your first code block it says there is an unexpected '=' but if I try your second block of code it says: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_the_terms(), 1 passed in /var/www/vhosts/staging.acquiredigital.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/acquire-child/single-products.php on line 17 and exactly 2 expected in /var/www/vhosts/staging.acquiredigital.com/httpdocs/wp/wp-includes/category-template.php:1236 -

Comment: This is after removing every other bit of content  from the page so I could see where the error is...

Comment: You may need to add `global $post;` before the code.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, still nothing - thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: To diagnose what is going on `echo print_r($post->ID, 1);`. If that prints the post ID, next `echo print_r(get_the_terms($post, 'product-category'), 1);`. If that does not return an array something is wrong. Make sure `product-category` is actually the taxonomy name.

Comment: The taxonomy name is: product_category - so with the underscore rather that the hyphen... so using this: <?php
echo print_r(get_the_terms($post, 'product_category'), 1);
?> - that kicks out a list of all of the taxonomies... Changing this in your original code though still doesn't have the desired effect :-/

Comment: If I add the global part before the code - would that make the line look like this? global $post; $product_category = get_the_terms($post, 'product-category')[0]; or am I writing hat wrong?

Comment: using this: $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_category');
if(!empty($terms)){
  foreach($terms as $term){
    $exampleName = $term->name;
    $exampleSlugs[] = $term->slug;
  }
}
 I can get the name of the category using: echo $exampleName; so that seems close! lol

Comment: Managed to get it working, inside a loop though... $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_category');
if(!empty($terms)){
  foreach($terms as $term){
    $exampleName = $term->name;
    $exampleSlugs[] = $term->slug;

    $category_colour_primary = get_field('category_colour_primary', $term);
    $category_colour_secondary = get_field('category_colour_secondary', $term);

  }
}

Comment: Thanks lot for all of your help :)

Comment: Nice! Add your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working with the following code:

```
<?php
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_category');
if(!empty($terms)){
  foreach($terms as $term){
    $exampleName = $term->name;
    $exampleSlugs[] = $term->slug;

    $category_colour_primary = get_field('category_colour_primary', $term);
    $category_colour_secondary = get_field('category_colour_secondary', $term);

  }
}
?>
```